# Rails fields_for 10 nested optional models, display some filled and some blank on edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model A that can have up to 10 associated models B in a one-to-many relationship. These nested models have just a string attribute representing a word.

I want to display a form to create/edit the parent model and all the nested children, displaying fields for the 10 possible models. Then, if I only fill up two of them, two models will be created.

Finally, when editing model A I need to display 10 fields, two of them filled up with the model B associated with A data, and the rest blank ready to fill.

Tried `fields_for`with an array, but it only displays fields for the already existing model B instances.

View:

```
= form_for @a, remote: true do |f|
  = f.text_field :title, placeholder: true
  = f.fields_for :bs, @a.bs do |ff|
    / Here, for the edit action, N text fields appear, being N equals to @soup.soup_words.size
    / and I need to display 10 fields everytime, because a Soup can have up to 10 SoupWord
    / For the new action, it should display 10 empty text fields.

    / Finally, if you fill three of the 10 fields, 
    / model A should have only 3 instances of model B associated. i.e if there were 4 filled and 
    / I set one of them blank, the model B instance should be destroyed.
    = ff.text_field :word, placeholder: true
= f.submit
```

Controller:

```
class Bs < ApplicationController
  def edit
    respond_to :js
    @soup = Soup.find params[:id]
  end

  def update
    respond_to :js
    puts params
  end
end
```

**Update**

Create and edit actions now work, just put a `reject_if` parameter in model A,

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :bs, reject_if: proc { |attrs| attrs[:word].blank? }
```

and set the `build` on the controller.

```
def new
  respond_to :js
  @a = A.new
  10.times { @a.bs.build }
end

def edit
  respond_to :js
  @a = Soup.find params[:id]
  @a.bs.size.upto(9) do |sw|
    @a.bs.build
  end
end
```

Now I need to destroy instances of model B if I set them blank in the edit action.

Comment: You need to seed the record with new children. `10.times { @a.bs.new }`. But you should show the code you have and focus on asking about one specific problem.

Comment: I updated the question with code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would delete nested records by using the `allow_destroy: true` option and by passing the `_destroy` param:

```
class Soup
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :soup_words, 
    reject_if: proc { |attrs| attrs[:word].blank? },
    allow_destroy: true
end
```

To get the behavior you want you can use javascript with a hidden input:

```
= form_for @soup, remote: true do |f|
  = f.text_field :title, placeholder: true
  = f.fields_for :soup_words, @soup.soup_words do |ff|
    = ff.text_field :word, class: 'soup_word', placeholder: true
    = ff.hidden_input :_destroy
  = f.submit
```

---

```
$(document).on('change', '.soup_word', function(){
  var $obj = $(this);
  if (!this.value || !this.value.length) {
    // set soup_word to be destroyed
    $obj.siblings('input[name~=_destroy]').val('1');
  }
  $obj.fadeOut(50);
});
```

Make sure you have whitelisted the `_destroy` and `id` params.

```
def update_params
  params.require(:soup).permit(:soup_words_attributes: [:word, :id, :_destroy])
end
```

Comment: After a few editings on your code I got it working:
Changes: `ff.hidden_input` -> `ff.hidden_field`
Remove `$obj.fadeOut(50)`
Changed `.siblings(...)` to `.next()`
Changed `.on('change')` -> `.on('input')`
Made an `else` to the JS `if` to set the value to 0 if filled up again
Changed the listener from `document` to `$('.soup_word')`
After all of this, it went working. Thank you!